# Why I getting "SMS and CALL_LOG permissions warning"

Tags: android, permissions, google-play

I have so many permission in my app but I dont have any call_log permission but Im getting this warning from play console . Is this common warning or this permissions below have hidden call_log permission.

[image]

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
            tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"
            tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Comment: no I dont have any

Comment: remove SEND_SMS

Comment: Sms ok but why call log

Comment: The warning shows permantently for you, right? I'm getting this once after a while, but it disappears after a site refresh. I'm not using any of those permissions as far as I know? I'm just a lil scared.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"
```

which comes under sms

Google Play may provide a temporary exception to apps that aren't Default SMS, Phone, or Assistant handlers when:

1. Use of the permission provides core app functionality to users
2. There is currently no alternative method to provide the core functionality

you must fill this [form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfbmF-9G249UDLJZpEvJpjgwP8rjvvLyWyNYnFPrsqYjMNckg/closedform) and google must approve it

[image]

you can find more info [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303)

**EDIT**

For any one who is still getting this error after removing the permissions . Try deleting all previous APK from your account (from alpha,beta, internal testing if any)

Comment: I remove this Send_SMS permission but I dont have any CALL_LOG permission. Why is this warning have CALL_LOG permission.

Comment: Google implemented this policy change with sms and call log together, so they might be sending common message which violates any policy

Comment: I have removed those permissions but still i am asking to fill that form forcefully, so how can i bypass that stupid form of google.

Comment: If you're still getting warning message in play store console. Follow [steps](https://gist.github.com/manishpatelgt/224a330a5d4c7eaf783ca3ff5d522274) and try again

Comment: I don't have SMS or Call Log permission but still, my app gets rejected?

Comment: @Tabishkhan see last sentence

Comment: What are the things I need to keep in mind If I am going to upload application for the first time with SEND_SMS permission?

Comment: Note that the permission declaration form via google docs was removed long back and it is now available in the new play console under the app content on the left.

Answer (score 8):

Please see the following instructions to submit the declaration form:

A1. Go to the Console > App release > Click ‘Create a release’ > Upload a new APK that you want to release 
A2. Retain the current version of APK
A3. Click ‘Add from library’ > Upload all active APKs to cover all permissions across the tracks in your app

You can find active APK in Release management > Artifact library

A4. Fill out the Permissions Declaration Form for extension 
‘Compliance status’ > check “No, this release does not meet the SMS and Call log”
‘Declarations’ > check all
A5. Click "Save" at the bottom of the page

After that, please stay on the same page and follow the next steps:

B1. Deactivate and remove ONLY the old APKs which you do not want to release. 
B2. Click "Save" again then select "Review"
B3. Then, you'll be able to release a new version of APK by clicking "Start Roll Out" button.

After finished all the steps, if your APK does NOT have sensitive or high-risk permissions anymore, please skip the steps below(C1~4) and no additional action is required. However, if you uploaded the new APK with sensitive or high-risk permissions, please note that your app will be removed after Mar 9, 2019.

If your new APK has sensitive or high-risk permissions & you want to utilize the permission after Mar 9, you need to finish the additional step to submit the declaration form to enable further review.

C1. After the new APK release(Step B1~3), please go to the Console > App release > Click ‘Create a release’

C2. Click ‘Add from library’ > Select the APK(which will be utilized after Mar.9) 
C3. Retain newly updated APK in step B3
C4. Fill out Permissions Declaration Form (not for extension),

‘Compliance status’ > check “Yes, this release meets the SMS and Call log”

Choose core functionalities as well

C5. Submit the form by Clicking “Save” at the bottom of the page

Also, to make sure your app be safe after Mar 9, please do not forget to update all the APKs(with sensitive or high-risk permission) in other track with the same steps.

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day, this procedure works if you want to publish new apk without sensitive permissions. In fact this is the only way to do it! Google has really made terrbile user interface without any information how to do it!

Comment: I'm not seeing this "No, this release does not meet the SMS and Call log" declaration. and my app still got removed even if I deleted the permission from android manifest..

Comment: @BobbyStenly : same for me, this option does not exist anymore and my app has also been suspended, whereas my current release does not contain SEND_SMS permission anymore. However, I found some active artefacts in the library section which have the SEND_SMS permission. They are the cause but I can't delete them. Anyone can help please?

Comment: @GrayFox I think I've seen the "No" option before, but If I select that option, I can't make any release. The last thing I tried is A1 til A4 and select one of available options at the declaration section. It's been 3 days and no love letter from google arrived.

Comment: @BobbyStenly : I finally found a solution for this issue without using the "No" option. In my case, I still had few active artifacts (visible in artifact library) because of some open tracks that used these APKs. I found them below the Alpha track section

Comment: @GrayFox i can't remove the apk's from the artifact

Comment: @MujammilAhamed yes, you can't delete an active APK from the artifacts library. You must find in which track (Release, Alpha, Beta, Internat testing or others) this APK is used. Then, upload a new APK on this track to deactivate the unwanted APK. Repeat this action if for each active APK. Hope this help

Answer (score 5):

[image]

> If you believe your app meets the policy requirements for acceptable
>   use or is eligible for an exception, submit a Permissions Declaration
>   Form as soon as possible for Google Play to review. You will be
>   notified if your request has been approved. You do not need to have
>   implemented APK changes in order to submit the Declaration Form.
>
> All Developers seeking to access the **`Call Log or SMS permissions`** must successfully complete the Permissions Declaration Form. By submitting this form, you verify that the app’s access to these permissions are only for the purposes described below and that you will submit an updated Form to seek additional approval prior to any revised / new scope for permission usage. You must fill out one Declaration Form for each app.
>
> You should only access **`Call Log or SMS permissions`** when your app falls within permitted uses, and only to enable your app’s core functionality.

Read

- [**Use of SMS or Call Log permission groups**](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303)
- [**Google Play Permissions Declaration Form**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfCnRaa4b1VuHhE4gVekWJc_V0Zt4XiTlsKsTipTlPg5ECA7Q/viewform)

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this issue and solved as follows.If you dont need sms and call logs permission in your app please remove all from your manifest file and take latest apk.

**Scenario 1:** If you have published your app as beta or alpha or internal testing, please update your old apk with the latest one. Here your old apk may contains those permissions they will reject your app once again.

**Scenario 2**:.If you really need those permissions then you have to follow the latest API's to handle SMS and CALL Log permissions.

They will check  all the old builds(beta,alpha and internal) for dangerous permissions.

For Ex : Hi,
Thanks for contacting the Google Play team.

I’ve reviewed your appeal request and found that

Version code 74 on Production track: SEND_SMS
Version code 46 on BETA track: READ_SMS, RECEIVE_SMS and SEND_SMS
Version code 50 on ALPHA track: READ_SMS, RECEIVE_SMS and SEND_SMS
Version code 53 on QA track: READ_SMS, RECEIVE_SMS and SEND_SMS

I find this info  when I appeal to play store team.

Answer (score 1):

you can remove permission of call and SMS permission (all SMS and call ) from your manifeast file, after then you have to fill Google Play Permissions Declaration Form before 
january 9, 2019 will have until March 9, 2019 to bring their app(s) into compliance.

If your app does not require access to Call Log or SMS permissions, you must remove these permissions from your app's manifest. Details on policy compliant alternative implementation are also detailed below.

For apps with Declaration Forms submissions received by Jan 9, 2019, Google Play, at its option, may grant extensions until March 9, 2019 for you to make changes to bring your app(s) into compliance with this Play policy. If you do not plan on using these permissions, but still require additional time to bring your app(s) into compliance, please complete the Declaration Form.

for more info please review on below link

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303
 and find the deceleration form which you can find in the below link:

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfCnRaa4b1VuHhE4gVekWJc_V0Zt4XiTlsKsTipTlPg5ECA7Q/viewform

Comment: I have removed those permissions but still i am asking to fill that form forcefully, so how can i bypass that stupid form of google.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. @RaviVaniya did you found a fix?

Comment: see , first of all , you need to check the permission in your manifest file , like sms , (Read sms , write sms , and Your app manifest requests the Call Log permission group (e.g. READ_CALL_LOG, WRITE_CALL_LOG, PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS) It must be actively registered as the default Phone or Assistant handler on the device.
Your app manifest requests the SMS permission group (e.g. READ_SMS, SEND_SMS, WRITE_SMS, RECEIVE_SMS, RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH, RECEIVE_MMS)

Answer (score 0):

If SMS and call is not the core feature of your app then its best to remove and use alternatives, as its difficult to get exception from google, and your application will get rejected right away.

Below alternative you can consider to initiate phone call : Don't use CALL permission use dialer instead.

```
    val intent = Intent().apply {
    action = Intent.ACTION_DIAL
    data = Uri.parse("tel:0123456789")
}
startActivity(intent)
```

To send Text message:

```
val intent = Intent().apply {
    action = Intent.ACTION_SENDTO
    data = Uri.parse("smsto:0123456789")
    putExtra("sms_body", "text message")
}
if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Reference : https://proandroiddev.com/no-more-sms-call-log-permissions-now-what-9b8226de7827

Answer (score 0):

see , first of all , you need to check the permission in your manifest file ,like  Call Log permission group (e.g. READ_CALL_LOG, WRITE_CALL_LOG, PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS)   It must be actively registered as the default Phone or Assistant handler on the device.Your app manifest requests the SMS permission group (e.g. READ_SMS, SEND_SMS, WRITE_SMS, RECEIVE_SMS, RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH, RECEIVE_MMS) , if this permission is available then you need to check the Default hander  on the google play console otherwise unchecked the checkbox.and you need to fill the declaration form on the google play console. its mandatory