# Publishing status: Rejected Playstore Android

Tags: android, permissions, google-play, android-permissions, publishing

I have removed all the sensitive permissions for the app.

In the Compliance status, 
I selected **Yes, this release meets the SMS and Call Log permissions policy**

In the Core functionality
I selected **SMS-based financial transactions and related activity where access is restricted to financial SMS transactions (for example, 5-digit messages)**

and submitted the app to playstore.

After reviewing the build got rejected and got this response,

The declared functionality {Default SMS handler (and any other core functionality usage while default handler), Default Phone handler (and any other core functionality usage while default handler)} is determined to be unnecessary or not aligned with the core functionality of your app.

I am not using any of the sensitive permissions but still, the build got rejected.

As I am not using the permission for the core functionality, it is not allowing the save and rollout without selecting any core functionality.

So, How to proceed with this to get the build approved.

Comment: But why are you using this facility? You don't need to use this if you just want to read OTP from sms, you can read the broadcast, and also SMS-based financial transaction is a different thing - which directly interacts with bank. like UPI

Comment: I was doing this earlier,but now I have removed the permission

Comment: try deleting all previous apks from google play, and proceed with only new one.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53955029/6478047 , check if you have any other permissions , else delete older APKS

Comment: @ManoharReddy I had one apk in beta release, so a created a new release in beta in which I have removed all the sensitive permission. And then released it to production. My app got updated on the playstore. But still did not get the approval or rejection email from google play

Comment: Hope you have a good luck this time

Comment: Ya lets see. But I am wondering that still why I did not receive any email. Because I have received the app update email.

Comment: You don't get an email on approval normally. You can just see in the Play console your app is published

Comment: @NickFortescue when our app is getting rejected, we are getting the email. So If the app is approved, there should be an email for the confirmation right?

Comment: I don't believe so. Rejection is unusual, and normally approval is common and fast. You just see the publish is successful

Comment: They have given deadline till March 9 to meet sms and call permission policy. If we fail then they will remove our apk from play store.How can we know that our app meets the new policies without approval email from google.