# My app Update rejected for violating the Permissions policy

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am updating my app in playstore. But its showing update rejected due to Permission Policy. I removed SMS and Call Permission  from manifest. But still its showing the same error. Please guide me regarding this.

My manifest is like this

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.RECORD_AUDIO" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" />
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /><permission
        android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Comment: I think you need to add the privacy policy url to update this application

Comment: Does your app has any runtime permissions?

Comment: @VrushiPatel yes.

Comment: @KarthikThunga Have you read this link https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/ ?

Comment: @VrushiPatel yes i read. I dont know which option i have to select(from core functionality list ) while uploading app. I selected Default SMS Handler.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53955029/6478047 might be useful

Comment: @ManoharReddy thanx a lot man..

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you have updated APK in your Alpha or Beta in your play store account if you set any APK in past for testing and its still there.(This was happen with me)
And you haven't any APK in Alpha & Beta than check your code properly, may you set any runtime permission for SMS or CALL

Comment: Have you check your Alpha or beta section?