# Notification from Google Play about your Permissions Declaration

Tags: android, google-play

I received a google email where he says this:

> The declared feature Default SMS, Default Dialer is allowed; however,
>   it will be unnecessary for the core functionality of your app.

My app uses text messages to contact an alarm system. I tried filling out the Google online form, but they sent me a new email telling me that I had time until March 8th to adjust my app.
What is it about? what changes do I have to make?

My app uses smsManager and the default SMS APP, because on some phones, smsmanager does not work.

By tomorrow I have to resolve, otherwise my app will be removed.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/53954921/6478047

Comment: Thanks. I must remove permis android.permission.SEND_SMS^ and use only runtime permission? i don't understand, sorry

Comment: See what permissions you have , You cannot have any sms or call related permission unless it is very important for functioning of app

Comment: If you need any sms or call permission then explain very detaily in declaration form why you need those permission for functioning of your app

Comment: If want to read some text message you send then you could use SMS Retriever API https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why I getting "SMS and CALL\_LOG permissions warning"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53954921/why-i-getting-sms-and-call-log-permissions-warning)

Comment: my app interacts with a gsm module. I tried to explain it to Google but they did not approve my request.

Answer (score 0):

SMS permission is used by many apps for fraud or malware. So Google is cracking down on the use of this permission, and has changed the rules for it.

- [The rules are here](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/)
- [A help centre page is here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303)
- [A blog post explaining it is here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/providing-safe-and-secure-experience.html)

The help center article gives a ways of accomplishing what you need to, without asking for the permission.

If none of the ways work for you, and Google don't accept your explanation for why it is critical then I'm afraid your app has to be removed.

You may wish to consider what your App would do if it was running on iOS. You couldn't send a text message without user interaction on iOS either.