# How to fix SMS permissions in Firebase phone authentication? There are no permissions mentioned in manifest to remove

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-play-console

Due to SMS permissions, Play Store removed my app. I have used Firebase phone authentication and did not ask any SMS permissions from the user and also nothing mentioned in the Manifest file. It still gives READ_SMS permission violations. I know Google Play services are reading SMS internally..how to solve this issue...please help

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53955029/6478047

Comment: I don't have SMS or Call Log permission but still, my app gets rejected? Google play services internally reading OTP sms for auto fill.

Comment: its pretty strange arent you using any of these https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303 ?

Comment: NO. Firebase phone auth is auto filling the otp from sms and its done by google play services

Comment: see the last point in my answer

Comment: There are no other alpha beta versions of app...its a single release

Comment: show your manifest file.

Answer (score 3):

SOLVED!!! I am using PayUMoney Sdk in app for payment integration and it's previous version has SMS verification which requires READ_SMS permissions in app. Just updated the PayUmoney sdk to latest version and issue is resolved successfully. Third party dependancies have separate manifest files. please check permissions in manifest files.